# Table - disable auto numbering

Tags: tables, numbering

I was wondering whether it was possible to skip numbering one of my tables and carry on numbering the rest as if that table was not there.

Comment: You can use only `tabular` inside some `center` without the `table` environment.

Comment: You can have a `table` environment *without* a `\caption`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the package caption and

```
\caption*
```

inside the table environment